# Ireport pdf export only showing in one page and landscape mode not good pdf

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I build a report with some informations in title band, detail band and associate column header band and then finaly 3 charts and 3 subreports in summary band.

My problem is that when the report is exported in pdf, even if the subreports are very long, the report is always displayed on a single page. This makes the report complicated to read. Also when the report is in landscape the information is centered in the middle with adobe reader. How to make the report appear on a page or multiple pages (dynamically) depending on the length of the data and make the report adjust automatically depending on orientation.

Please see some screenshot

[image: ireport design mode]

[image: Print preview]

Print preview

[image]

[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: `My problem is that when the report is exported in pdf, even if the subreports are very long, the report is always displayed on a single page.` - Looks like you are using Ignore Pagination

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @AlexK . You save my life. Thank you once again. After uncheck ignore pagination the output is correct but it happens that the information at the level of the summary does not cut well and leaves large areas empty. I have updated my question with an image.